# MATLAB - concatenating items within a cell array

Tags: matlab, arrays, cell, concatenation

I have a cell array:

```
X =

{1x2} {1x2}


X{1} = '' A

X{1 2} = 10 113
```

I wish to concatenate the sub cells in such a way that

```
 Y = 10 113A
```

Thanks,
S :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y = cellfun(@(a, b) sprintf('%d%s', b, a), x{1}, x{2}, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have this cell array for `X`:

```
X = {{'' 'A'} {10 113}};
```

You can create your array `Y` using [INT2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/int2str.html) and [STRCAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/strcat.html):

```
Y = strcat(int2str([X{2}{:}].'),X{1}.').';
```

Answer (score 0):

The Matlab File Exchange has a function written to do precisely this. [uniqueRowsCA](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25917-unique-rows-for-a-cell-array)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I added some info to help find the link should it change (unlikely with the MFE). Not sure what the essential parts of this would be.

Answer (score -1):

For those interested, I think I found a solution.

I redefined my cell array as:

```
X1 =

{1x2}

X1 = '' 'A'

X2 = 

[1x2 double]

X2 = 10 113
```

I then applied this for loop:

```
NUM = [];

for i = 1:size(X2')              #take the transpose of X2
    p = num2str(X2(i));          #convert doubles to strings
    str = STRCAT(p, X1(i));      #concatenate
    NUM = [NUM str];             #add to another array
end


NUM = '10' '113A'
```

I am sure there is a more efficient way but MATLAB and I will probably never be on good terms. Sometimes quick and dirty is sufficient!

Cheers,
S :-)